# Looping through list of dicts and appending to csv file - index error

Tags: python, api, for-loop, index-error

I'm trying append values to a csv file by looping through the list then looping through dicts of a json data but i get a index erorr:

```py
import csv
data=json_resp.json()

with open('Meteroits.csv','w+') as file:
    writer=csv.DictWriter(file,fieldnames=['name','id','nametype','recclass','mass','fall','year','reclat','reclong','geolocation'])
    writer.writeheader()

    for i in range(len(data)):
        for x in data[i]:
            name=x[1]
            i_d=x[2]
            nametype=x[3]
            recclass=x[4]
            mass=x[5]
            fall=x[6]
            year=x[7]
            reclat=x[8]
            reclong=x[9]
            geolocation=x[10]
            writer.writerow({'name':name,'id':i_d,'nametype':nametype,'recclass':recclass,'mass':mass,'fall':fall,'year':year,'reclat':reclat,'reclong':reclong,'geolocation':geolocation})
```

I'm getting the error at `index 4`:

```
---> 12             recclass=x[4]
IndexError: string index out of range
```

And here's a sample of data:

```
{
  'name': 'Abee',
  'id': '6',
  'nametype': 'Valid',
  'recclass': 'EH4',
  'mass': '107000',
  'fall': 'Fell',
  'year': '1952-01-01T00:00:00.000',
  'reclat': '54.216670',
  'reclong': '-113.000000',
  'geolocation': {'latitude': '54.21667', 'longitude': '-113.0'}
}
```

Comment: You seem to be indexing starting at 1. It would be easier to comment if you showed where the IndexError occurs.

Comment: Your sample of data does not fit your description of the json content as "list of dicts".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is

- `i` is one index
- `data[i]` is one item, a `dict`
- `x` is a key of the `data[i]` dict, the first one being `'name'`
- `x[1]` is the letter `n`, ... `x[3]` the letter `'e'`, so `x[4]` is out of range

Just write the dict as you have it already

```
with open('Meteroits.csv', 'w+') as file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(file,
                            fieldnames=['name', 'id', 'nametype', 'recclass', 'mass',
                                        'fall', 'year', 'reclat', 'reclong', 'geolocation'])
    writer.writeheader()
    for item in data:
        writer.writerow(item)
```

Or just use `pandas`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.to_csv('Meteroits.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that `x` is the key of the dict, and not the dict itself. It should be:

```
for i in range(len(data)):
    new_dict = {}
    for x, val in data[i].items():
        new_dict[x] = val
    writer.writerow(new_dict)
```

Comment: You're just copying the dict, the same way

Comment: Agree, I thought there is a reason the OP wanted to deconstruct the dict and construct a new one.